# Simple Action Loop

Tags: swift, loops, skaction

I am trying to repeat a set of actions by running them through a loop. My loop is fine when running something else, but it seems to have trouble running the actions. My code is as follows:

```
let pulse1 = SKAction.scaleTo(2.0, duration: 1.0)
let pulse2 = SKAction.scaleTo(0.5, duration: 1.0)
var i = 0

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

for var i = 0; i <= 100; i++ { 
self.sun.runAction(pulse1)
self.sun.runAction(pulse2)

}
```

This will cause the node to pulse1 and pulse2  each once but never again. If I add

```
println("")
```

to the loop, it runs whatever text properly, but for some reason doesn't run the actions like it runs the text. Or maybe it does and I don't understand how SKAction works? Either way, the loop is executing properly, I believe. I am not quite sure what's wrong with the SKAction call in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

`scaleTo` simply changes the node's scale.  Once pulse1 goes to 2.0 and pulse2 gets to 0.5, `runAction` runs repeatedly but you never change the scale for either pulse ever again.

That's why you're only seeing it do work the first time.

Instead of using a for loop, try something like this:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        let pulse = SKAction.scaleTo(2.0, duration: 1.0)
    } else {
        let pulse = SKAction.scaleTo(0.5, duration: 1.0)
    }

    [self.sun runAction:pulse completion:^{

        if( i < 100 )
        {
            didMoveToView(view);
        }

    }];
}
```

Comment: Ok so I nested: 'if (i % 2 == 0) {pulse1 = SKAction.scaleTo(3.0, duration: 1.0) pulse2 = SKAction.scaleTo(0.7, duration: 1.0)}' It didn't seem to help. Again, I printed some text to make sure it was all running properly and it was. I must be pretty confused about how this action works. I assumed it would just inflate and deflate according to the original nodes initial size?

Comment: @terranceW both are supposed to be pulse1, not pulse1 and pulse 2 respectively. The idea is that when `i` is even you increase the size and when it's odd you decrease the size. All of the scaling seems to be relative to the original size.

Comment: Right, I got that. What I'm having trouble with now is the syntax of the second part. I am new to Swift and I don't really know what process is being utilized in the '[self.sun runAction: pulse completion:^{' part of his response. I am getting errors, I understand that I'm supposed to enter parameters to whatever that is, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use

```
         class func repeatAction(_ action: SKAction,
              count count: Int) -> SKAction
```

Put as many single actions in a sequence an run repeatAction for x times.